# Time data type not available in SQL Server Express 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm creating a database for some sports records. I want to record the date of the event, and the score (which is a time value). So I want to store time and date in two separate columns. Should be able to do this in SQL Server 2014 with the 'date' and 'time' data types, right? I use SQL Server 2008 at work, and I have these data types available to me there.

I've just created a brand new database in SQL Express 2014. I'm new to creating databases - my job involves writing reports - so it's very possible I've done something wrong during creation. When I use SSMS to create a table and columns, 'time' or 'date' aren't in the data type drop down. I've tried to write it into the create table manually, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677243.aspx) but I get:

```
Msg 2715, Level 16, State 7, Line 13
Column, parameter, or variable #5: Cannot find data type time.
```

I get the same issue with 'date'. I also found something online about compatibility mode, so I tried the following

```
alter database [Records] 
set compatibility_level = 100;
go
```

But that results in

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '100'.
```

The syntax is exactly as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933794.aspx). I've tried the value 120 as well, as per the article. Same syntax error.

I queried what the compatibility level currently is with

```
use [Records]
go
select compatibility_level
from sys.databases where name = 'records';
go
```

That works fine, and the answer is 90.

So now I'm stuck. Can't see anything obvious in the database properties either.

Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: compat level will not add or remove types, are you *positive* your connected to an SQL Server 2014? Check with `select @@version` (do it even if you are positive)

Comment: It seems like you are connecting to 2005 instance, as "alter database .. set compatibility_level = 100;" is not working. It was introduced with SQL 2008.

Comment: Can you try executing a minimal create statement to see what error you get: `create table time_test (the_time time);` ?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compatability level 90 = 2005. 100 = 2008, 110 = 2012, 120 = 2014. If your getting 90 back, it's set to not support data types introduced in and after 2008

Comment: It's definitely SQL Server Express 2014, but I wonder now if it's the instance that is the problem. I imported the AdventureWorks database into it and I'm using that same instance. Might have misconfigured something during that step.

Comment: Yep so select @@version returns 2005. I'll probably delete the instance and start again. Thanks all.